# Every locally Compact Hausdorff Space is Regular.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, separation-axioms, compactification

**Every locally Compact Hausdorff Space is  Regular**

$Proof$:Let $X=$locally compact+$T_2\implies X^*$ is compact+$T_2\implies X^*$ is Normal($T_4$)$\implies X^*$ is Regular$\implies X$ is regular($T_3$)*Subspace of regular space is regular*)

**Note:**$X^*$ is one point compactification of $X$.

Are my Arguments true??

Answer (score 1):

Yes that’s complete correct. Of course you *do* have to know (theorem for you?) that $X^\ast$ is indeed Hausdorff when $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff.